# Should a question about correct ventilation solution for a single rack be asked on SU or SF?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am running a homelab with a couple heat-producing items in a relatively small room. I'm thinking of punching a hole in the wall and exhausting the heat from the items to the adjacent room that has only plants.

Should the question regarding the size and capacity of the ventilator be asked on Super User or Server Fault? What about the effect on the room itself? Should a question on that be asked on some other Stack Exchange forum (is there one for buildings?)?

Comment: I believe neither of the sites you mention would be a good place for asking this.

Comment: You could take the tour and read the [help] in [diy.se], you'd need to give some idea of the energy that needs to be dissipated, you don't want to end-up roasting all the plants.

Comment: Should you**R** s**E**arch fail to pro**D**uce results, there is a very specific an**D** act**I**ve communi**T**y for **Homelabs** off site which cover a very large variety of topics and problems you are likely to encounter. Good luck in your HVAC endeavours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>Not Server Fault</s> (updated by an SF moderator)

Although there is a somewhat related tag,

- [physical-environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/physical-environment)

...questions about home use are off-topic.  If this were an office environment, punching a hole in the wall to dissipate some of the heat into the adjacent room would not be a professional approach.

Maybe it could best to try

- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
  Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people seeking specific hardware recommendations.
  Possible related tags:

  - [ventilation](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ventilation)
  - [cooling](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling)
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/
  Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts.
  Possible related tags:

  - [cooling](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling)
- https://engineering.stackexchange.com/
  Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals and students of engineering. 
  Possible related tags:

  - [hvac](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hvac)
  - [cooling](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling)
- https://diy.stackexchange.com/
  Home Improvement Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
  contractors and serious DIYers.
  Possible related tags:

  - [hvac](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hvac)